# Chosen drop list outside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I've been using the Chosen plugin for my app, but I've run into several major issues. They all come down to the same thing - the drop list is created as a sibling div to the select element, so it is forced to render inside the parent div. Which, in my case, is set to `overflow: auto`, which creates undesired behavior if the select is near the bottom of the visible area.

Obviously the solution would be to append the drop-down element to `body` and use dynamic positioning. I could probably fix it by spending some time with the Chosen code, but I was wondering if there's an existing workaround/branch (the only ones I could find are dated several years ago and are probably missing lots of newer features from the main version). I would imagine this is a pretty common use case (using it inside a dialog comes to mind, too).
Also, it should probably be able to drop up, too, in case it is near the bottom of the page.

**Update**: I expected this to be a known issue so I thought an example wasn't needed. In any case, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ooonqtox/

Comment: Please poste a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. It would help you get better answers.

Comment: Dynamically positioning a div can cause headaches. Why do the Chosen examples work but yours doesn't? Have you explicitly stated `overflow: auto` yourself? If so, why? I'd recommend (kind of relating to the comment above me) that you post some code (or better still, a jsfiddle) so we can have a better look.

Comment: @riv - you can **overwrite** the default css class **`chosen-drop`** for this

Comment: @Prog: overwriting a css wouldn't achieve anything as the drop list has to be placed outside the parent div in order to render outside it. @DeeMac: I use `overflow: auto` to create a scrollable area, obviously. AFAIK some jQuery UI widgets (such as autocomplete) create dynamically positioned elements and it works well for them.